# Google Apps Scripts - Email as string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

If I get a variable and enter an email address, like so..

```
var emailAddress = 'example@hotmail.com.au';
```

Then this code (Below) will work and send an email to the above address.

```
var sendMail = MailApp.sendEmail({ to: emailAddress, subject: emailSubject, message: emailMessage});
```

If I dynamically enter an email address (through a google form) that is in column (10), the code above will fail. Am I not passing it as a string?

```
var emailAddress = e.values[10];
```

I have also tried the following to fix a sting issue:

```
var emailAddress = String(e.values[10]);
```

Comment: Use `Logger.log` to print `emailAddress`?

Comment: Would you store the print in a variable i.e. var printEmail = Logger.log(email) or is Logger used to print? I.e. var sendMail = MailApp.sendEmail({ to: Logger.log(emailAddress), subject: etc etc

Comment: Use `Logger.log(emailAddress)`, because `Logger.log` return Logger it self.

Comment: No, the log is for debugging. What does it show in the script editor after you run the function?

Comment: Column 10, or Column 11? [10] is Column 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already faced this issue, we can solve this issue by using serializedArray 
example: #emailForm is the id for the form we need to put email value to any variable I stored in newValues then get emailAddress as a string(var emailId = newValues.email.value;)

```
   var formValues = $("#emailForm").serializeArray();
    var newValues = {};
    formValues.forEach(function(x){
           newValues[x.name] = x;
    });
var emailId = newValues.email.value;
```